# Why doesn't finish signup work?

Tags: bug, website, openid

I was first going to ask this on Meta, but that was not possible because it required me to do "finish signup" which doesn't work for me. I always have this thing at the top of the screen next to my name that says "finish signup". [image: Finish Signup]

So, I click on it, and see what happens. I get to this screen, and I enter a password.

[image: Entering Password]

After I do that, it redirects me back to the electrical engineering home and it still says "finish signup". What is wrong with this, and Why can't I sign up, I think I have enough reputation. I wish to be able to vote, so this is why I want to finish signup.

Comment: I've had a lot problems with SE's OpenID - for example that the login page gives a 404. Not sure how to fix this, you might want to try [metase], the general meta, instead to get a faster response.

Comment: Huh, and I thought only those with the dotted border were marked for extra hassling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create Google account.
2. Use Google account to log in to EE with Open ID.
3. See [this page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I didn't try your answer, but it just started working when I voted on a stack overflow question, because stack overflow allowed me